# Trying out Steam's JSON API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to learn how to get items, through API's. And I'm currently trying to get an Avatar from a Steam API.

This is the jQuery I've wrote thus far:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561197960435530", function(json) {
  console.log(json);
  $('#poster').html('<img id="thePoster" src=' + json[0].avatarmedium.url + ' />');
});
```

When I do:

```
console.log(json);
```

I get this result:

```
response: Object
players: Array[1]
0: Object
avatar: "steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4.jpg"
avatarfull: "steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_full.jpg"
avatarmedium: "steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_medium.jpg"
communityvisibilitystate: 3
lastlogoff: 1448309489
loccityid: 3961
loccountrycode: "US"
locstatecode: "WA"
personaname: "Robin"
personastate: 0
personastateflags: 0
primaryclanid: "103582791429521412"
profilestate: 1
profileurl: "/id/robinwalker/"
realname: "Robin Walker"
steamid: "76561197960435530"
timecreated: 1063407589
```

And I'm trying to access the avatermedium URL you see above, so I simply show the avatar of a Steam profile, on the website.

But I can't seem to access it, if that makes sense.
How do I do it?

Comment: `json.players[0].avatarmedium`?...

Comment: If i use: json.avatarmedium.url i get "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined", and if i use: json.players[0].avatarmedium - i get "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the response is an object, the array is nested two levels down in the `players` property. So it should be:

```
json.response.players[0].avatarmedium
```

There's no `.url` property of `avatarmedium`, it's just a string.

Comment: I've deleted the host in the question above, because I'm not allowed to have more than 2 links in my question, since im new here :-)
- I've tried that as well, but it just gives me "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Comment: Is `response` also a property in the object? I thought that was just you showing that this was the output of `console.log()`.

Comment: Excactly, it's a property too.

Comment: @Nikmanto I don't think URLs in code blocks should count against the link limit. Maybe the problem is that you didn't put the output in a code block.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying this:

`json.response.players[0].avatarmedium`

You need to add 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/':

```
'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/' + json.response.players[0].avatarmedium
```

```js
$.getJSON("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561197960435530", function(json) {
  console.log(json);
  $('#poster').html('<img id="thePoster" src=' + 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/' + json.response.players[0].avatarmedium + ' />');
});
```

Hoe that helps

Comment: It gives me this error: "http://localhost:8888/api-test/undefined 404 (Not Found)".

- Sorry if i sound like a "noob". But it just dosen't make any sense to me :-(

Comment: You need to put `http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/`in front of the url. I edited my answer.

Comment: I am not sure about the `undefined`in your comment. Could you please post what you coded excactly?

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, I've used 3 hours, trying to figure this out by myself! :)

- Where did you get the Cdn from? if i may ask?